# Linux local Password Policy doesn't apply when creating new user

Tags: linux, security, configuration

I'm trying to implement a *password security policy* on my Linux Mint machine.
I configured the `/etc/pam.d/common-password` file with the following lines.

```
password requisite pam_pwquality.so retry=3 minlen=10 dcredit=-1 ucredit=-1 lcredit=-1 ocredit=-2 
password [success=1 default=ignore] pam_unix.so obscure use_authtok try_first_pass sha512 shadow
```

Whenever I create (`adduser test`) a new user, I just get **a warning** (password too short, 1 digit missing etc.). If I *retype* the password, the users gets **created**.

How can I configure to force the password to meet the requirements?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I see - just execute `password --expire user` once, that user is created. In this case, you (as root) do not care about password complexity. But the user would have to set a new password the next time he try to login - and that password change will obey the rules in `common-password`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked!

Answer (score -1):

I configured the file `/etc/security/pwquality.conf` . Now everything works perfectly!

Comment: It would be good to know _how_ you configured that file.  Expand your answer to include more details about the cause of the issue and how you resolved it.  This would benefit others with the same or similar problems.  See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer